# Where is the List<MyClass> object buffer maintained? Is it on RAM or HDD?

Tags: c#, .net, list, memory-management

My question might sound a little vague. But what I want to know is where the `List<>` buffer is maintained.

I have a list `List<MyClass>` to which I am adding items from an infinite loop. But the RAM consumption of the Windows Service(inside which I am creating the List) never goes beyond 17 MB. In fact it hovers between 15-16MB even if I continue adding items to the List.
I was trying to do some Load Testing of My Service and came across this thing.

Can anyone tell me whether it dumps the data to some temporary location on the machine, and picks it from there as I don't see an increase in RAM consumption.

The method which I am calling infinitely is AddMessageToList().

```
class MainClass
{
    List<MessageDetails> messageList = new List<MessageDetails>();
    private void AddMessageToList()
    {
        SendMessage(ApplicationName,Address, Message);
        MessageDetails obj= new MessageDetails();
        obj.ApplicationName= ApplicationName;
        obj.Address= Address;
        obj.Message= Message;            
        lock(messageList)
        {
            messageList.Add(obj);
        }
    }
}
class MessageDetails
{

    public string Message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string ApplicationName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's approx size of a single instance of your MyClass object? Also, how long did you run your infinite loop?

Comment: Does your infinite loop do anything besides add stuff to the list?

Comment: Sample Code?  Also, the List<T> doesn't store any objects (at least for the class variation) it keeps a list of references to objects which are stored elsewhere (the heap in most implementations).

Comment: I suppose the code of your infinite loop is also needed, as there is most likely the "mistake".

Comment: @Ray See my updated answer - you're most likely not storing the list at all, instead, it's being thrown away after each request.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer to your question is: "In Memory".

That can mean RAM, and it can also mean the hard drive (Virtual Memory). The OS memory manager decides when to page memory to Virtual Memory, which mostly has to do with how often the memory is accessed (though I don't pretend to know Microsoft's specific algorithm).

You also asked why your memory usages isn't going up. First off, a MegaByte is a HUGE amount of memory. Unless your class is quite large, you will need a LOT of them to make a MB appear. Eventually your memory usage should go up though.

Comment: Ok. So when you say OS memory manager decides to page memory to Virtual Memory, in that case the RAM consumption wont go up?
Also the RAM usage increases initially when I start the infinite loop. But becomes consistent on reaching ~17MB

Comment: @Ray Physical RAM consumption won't go up, but most (not all) memory metrics count virtual memory which includes the page file.

Comment: A MB isn't that big. `byte[1048576]` doesn't seem that hard

Comment: @Cruncher, I agree, but we don't know how many objects he actually created. A million-element collection is somewhat uncommon in C#. Creating an array (as you suggested) would certainly take up that large amount of memory.

Comment: @LordTakkera, I am creating the list object globally so its created only once. But `MessageDetails` object I am creating inside the infinite loop so its scope is only till method level. I have mentioned the result which I am getting using `GC.GetTotalMemory()` in the comment above. Is it helpful for you to conclude or you need more data?

Comment: @Ray, I don't see anything that would cause your memory usage to stop increasing (though you haven't posted the "infinite" loop yet). Obviously if something was consuming your list that would affect it as well...

Comment: @LordTakkera The code I have posted, in description, is within a WCF service hosted inside a Windows service and I am calling the `AddMessageToList()` method infinitely from my WCF Client. And I my watching the RAM usage of the Windows service.

Answer (score 8):

In general C# objects are created from the Heap, which resides in memory.  If you want to store things on disk there are ways to go about it, but a standard `List<T>` will live in memory.

When you create an object it will occupy a certain number of bytes in memory plus the size of the pointers used to reference it.  Adding it to a list only adds a pointer to the object you've already created, so if you're adding lots of copies of the same instance into the list, it won't grow as fast as you expect.

If you really want to test the impact of large data structures on your memory, you're going to have to ramp up the numbers.  A few thousand average objects aren't going to occupy much memory, but a few million might.

You might also be interested in the [`GC.GetTotalMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) method and its friends.

Comment: I used the GC.GetTotalMemory() method and I can see an increase starting with **1011160** and going to a maximum of **7786216** and then coming down to **4310696** and hovering in 50's and 60's. I got this values over a period of 12 hours and my infinite loop was running continuously. Any conclusion or you need more data?

Comment: I can run a program out of memory in a couple of seconds if I try hard enough, so I suspect that your list isn't growing as fast as you think.  How many entries in the list?  How many bytes per entry on average?  You can get an idea by adding up the lengths of the strings, plus 8 bytes or so per string for overheads, plus whatever other data the records are storing... so how big are they really?

Comment: Just read the other comments... there are certain situations where your app may effectively be restarted by the framework - happens in web services all the time.  Set up your WCF service to return the total number of entries in the list and monitor that as well to see if the service is being restarted or the static list is being reinitialized.

Answer (score 5):

Note that pretty much all memory on Windows (and .NET) is Virtual Memory - its "real, physical" location is arbitrary, Windows memory management handles that. However, regardless of whether it's currently using physical RAM or a page file on the HDD, it will show up as committed private memory.

So it's up to how you're actually creating the items and adding them to the `List<T>`. How many objects are there? Are you adding the same object over and over again, or creating a new one every time? Are you using the same List instance, or are you creating others? Do you keep references to the created objects (and List instances), or are you throwing them away? Do you actually do *anything* with the object / list? If not, the optimizer might have removed the code alltogether (it's very conservative, though, so I wouldn't count on that in adding items to a list - that's a very complex scenario with possible side effects).

In the lowest memory ideal case, you could be using about four bytes per list item, that's not much - you'd need 262 144 items to consume a single MiB of memory!

Show us your code, the whole loop and it's surroundings. Then we can tell you what you're *actually* doing.

**EDIT**: This is in a WCF service? You should have said so before. Where do you *store* the `MainClass` class? If it's inside the WCF service class, it might not last longer than a single request. And even if you fix that, and store it in something a bit more persistent, like a static class, you get into the complexities of when everything is collected, how the service is being restarted etc. If you need the data to be safely held for longer than a single request, storing it in process memory isn't good enough. If you don't care that the data can get thrown away once in a while, you can make the `List` instance static (it's not going to be shared nor persisted otherwise). Otherwise, use a database.

Answer (score 0):

Speculating from your sparse description, there are two sorts of things you might not realize:

- The 15-16 MB usage you see might have nothing to do with the size of your list: it could be the memory requirements for the rest of the program, and your list only consumes a negligible amount of memory in comparison. Even if you don't explicitly create objects, your program still has to load libraries and stuff, which takes memory.
- I don't know C# so I don't know if this applies to `List`, but one of the standard container class implementations to dynamically allocate an array to hold the objects... and if the array is ever filled, then you allocate a new array twice the size and copy everything over to the new array and continue along (the actual ratio may be something other than $2$). This can have the effect that your memory usage remains constant for a long time, until you finally fill up the array and then it suddenly jumps up in size, only to remain constant again for a long time.